# Culture specific string equality (danish)

Tags: c#, localization, string-comparison

In danish the double letter "aa" corresponds to the single letter "å", which in practice means that cities such as Århus and Ålborg can be spelled Aarhus and Aalborg. Since "å" is the last letter of the alphabet, this means that when using String.Compare or sorting a list, these words are sorted last, and this works fine - as several users in here have discovered.

However it doesn't seem to know that the two are actually the same, since string.Equals, string.Compare and StringComparer all return false:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK");
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK");

string str1 = "Aalborg";
string str2 = "Ålborg";

StringComparer.Create(CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("da-DK"), true).Equals(str1, str2); // False
string.Equals(str1, str2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase); // False
string.Compare(str1, str2, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase); // 1
```

So how does one go about testing string equality across different locales?

Comment: Is your question, for instance, how can we compare a Turkish string with a Danish one?

Comment: You seem to be expecting that string comparison would magically apply some language-specific convention-specific rules. Well, it doesn’t. The strings “å” and “aa” are distinct, just as “ae” and “ä” and “æ” are all distinct, even though some conventions allow “ä” and “æ” to be replaced by “ae” when people don’t know how to produce the correct characters. This is not a character-level issue at all, and if you want to take such fallback/tradition replacements into account, you need to code them separately.

Comment: Indeed I did, but is that "magically"? Maybe it's just me, but I don't think it's entirely logical that you can correctly sort the strings, but not compare them. But I guess maybe it would be too much work to design and maintain it - unfortunately - since when comparing addresses in different languages, you effectively need to know all of these language-specific conventions, and code them yourself - as maccrobbsen suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to write your own equality comparer, e. g.

```
public class MyDanishStringComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
  public bool Equals(string x, string y)
  {
    return x.Replace("Å", "Aa").Equals(y.Replace("Å", "Aa"));
  }
}
```

that can be invoked like that:

```
public class MyTest
{
  string s1 = "Ålborg";
  string s2 = "Aalborg";
  MyDanishStringComparer comparer = new MyDanishStringComparer();

  comparer.Equals(s1, s2);
}
```